# Shell script variables to returning values

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I have a config file something like below.

```
_ispip=$_octet.129
_octet=10.89.2
_rxpip=$_octet.132
```

And when i try to echo the value its not printing the full values for the 1st variable. Is there a easy way to fix this?

```
# source test.cfg
# echo $_ispip
.129

# echo $_octet
10.89.2

# echo $_rxpip
10.89.2.132
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` doesn't have lazy evaluation, it will try to replace `$_octet` when you refer to it. If you do this before the assignment, you get an empty string.

You need to put the `_octet` assignment before `_ispip`.

```
_octet=10.89.2
_ispip=$_octet.129
_rxpip=$_octet.132
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My configuration file as 1000+ lines. Using the source command its loading the variables to memory and using it when needed. So rearranging the values is kind a tough job here. Any other ways you recommend?

Comment: @SandoshKumarP Automate rearranging the values ;)

Comment: @SandoshKumarP How many of the variables are referenced in other variables? You only need to rearrange those variables, put them all at the top.